# Does google dojo API need JVM?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am planning to use Google provided Dojo API's does it need Java SE or JVM to be pre-installed in the machine?
    i think we don't need it but i need some clarification

I was referring to this google DOJO API's https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#dojo

Thanks 
Gana

Comment: Google provides Dojo? And what machine are you asking about? The development/build server? Or the end user's?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#dojo this is the one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Google is just providing webhosting for a JavaScript library.

Java and JavaScript have about as much in common as Car and Carpet. You don't need a JVM to use a JavaScript library.